# Face Recognition with one shot learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm a newbie at deep learning. I started with face recognition example and I found that there are 2 types of model base on data for pre-trained.
1. One-shot learning with siamese network: Which we can use few data for train the model.
2. Convolutional neural network: Need numerous data for train the model.

Could we combine these methods is using one-shot learning with CNN in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

As my knowledge, CNN needs lots of data for training the model.So we cant implement one shot learning features on CNN

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do one-shot learning by using a pre-trained CNN, for instance FaceNet or Vgg2. Using Keras you can easily load these models:

```
from keras_vggface.vggface import VGGFace
model = VGGFace(model='resnet50', include_top=False,
                    input_shape=(224, 224, 3), pooling='avg')
```